# Power flow in a waveguide : telegraph equations

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electricity, waveguide

I am reading [this document](https://uwaterloo.ca/institute-for-quantum-computing/sites/ca.institute-for-quantum-computing/files/uploads/files/mqosc_final.pdf) in which we study propagation of voltage and current on a waveguide. The goal is to do the quantization of the waveguide afterwards.

Basically everything starts from the transmission line model consisting of a succession of inductance and capacitor.

[image]

It leads to the telegraph equations:

$$ \partial_x V(x,t)=-l_0 \partial_t I(x,t) $$
$$ \partial_x I(x,t)=-c_0 \partial_t V(x,t) $$

Where $l_0$ and $c_0$ are the inductance and capacitance per unit length of this waveguide. $Z=\sqrt{\frac{l_0}{c_0}}$ is the waveguide impedance.

We can rewrite the solutions in terms of propagating forward and backward waves, in practice we have:

$$V(x,t)=V_{out}(t-x/c)+V_{in}(t+x/c)$$
$$I(x,t)=I_{out}(t-x/c)+I_{in}(t+x/c)=\frac{1}{Z}\left( V_{out}(t-x/c) - V_{in}(t+x/c) \right)$$

We assume the line is defined on $x \in [0,+\infty]$. The outgoing signal thus evolve toward increasing $x$ and the incoming (the excitation the experimentalist has put) travels toward the decreasing $x$. In $x=0$ there is a load (you can put a resistor or an LC circuit if you wish).

**My question is the following:**

On page 5, equation 1.14 is written that the net power flowing to the right of the line is:

$$P=\frac{1}{Z}\left(V_{out}(0,t)^2-V_{in}(0,t)^2 \right)$$

I assume that for any $x$ we actually have this more general formula:

$$P(x,t)=\frac{1}{Z}\left(V_{out}(x,t)^2-V_{in}(x,t)^2 \right)$$

**Where does this come from ?**

**Does that physically correspond to the Poynting vector of the $E$ and $B$ fields integrated on a slice of the waveguide ?**

**At first view the formula "looks reasonable", it corresponds to $V_{out}I_{out}-V_{in}I_{in}$, but taking a closer look, the dissipater power around a load is $V*I$ where $V$ is the voltage difference around the load. But here there is not really such load in $x$. I am confused.**

Comment: The power going to the right of $x=0$ is $V_{out}^2/Z$, going to the left of $x=0$ is  $V_{in}^2/Z$, so their difference is what is dissipated at that location; the transmission line itself is assumed to be lossless and the load defining your voltage difference is what dissipates.

Comment: @hyportnex thank you for your answer. What confuses me the most is how to be sure that the power going to the right is indeed $V_{out} I_{out}$. Indeed from "usual" electric vision, there is no propagation phenomenons. So the power around a load is $P=V*I$. Here I have some propagation phenomenon so I must be carefull with what I can or cannot say with the usual non propagative electric relations. How to be sure that the power going toward the right is indeed $V_{out}*I_{out}$. I guess it can be showed making link with E.M via Poynting vector of the outgoing waves.

Comment: Sticking on the electric vision, is there a rigorous way to see that $V_{out} I_{out}$ is indeed the power going to the right ? How to prove it ? Maybe the only rigorous way to see it is via poynting vector from E.M but if there is a purely but rigorous way to see it electrically I am interested.

Comment: Kirchhoff's law has energy conservation built in , and "telegrapher's equation" representing a single propagating TEM mode is a slight generalization of Kirchhoff's (infinite number of L's and C's on a ladder), so you have energy conservation there too; no need for Poynting.